# try_file is not using fastcgi

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, fastcgi

I am running Wordpress through nginx and php-fpm. When a file that exists is requested, it works fine but when try_pass attempts to rewrite the URL to index.php, the browser just downloads the source of the PHP file. How can I get try_files to pass index.php to fastcgi?

Here is my nginx config

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /home/gausie/mywebsite.com/;
        index index.php;

        server_name mywebsite.com;

        location = /favicon.ico {
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

        location = /robots.txt {
                allow all;
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~* \.php$ {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

        location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
                expires max;
                log_not_found off;
        }

}
```

I've basically borrowed this from the nginx wiki so I can't see why it doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

So... with no changes to the file at all it's fixed itself after just waiting.

I'd appreciate if anyone knows why it took so long to work though...